# Goto method of class shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a tool that will list failed tests, and I would like a way to open a fully qualified class and goto a method in Eclipse with a single string I can copy from the results. It can use any pattern whatsoever (I can change the test results layout), but could be something like this example:

```
com.my.package.StringUtilTest:testValueOf
```

I shall use it for re-running tests, but could work with any methods. It could go to the first option when there are overloads (won't matter for me). It could also list all options and allow me to paste the string and enter to go to the first option (being the only one in my case), or selecting the correct one from the very narrowed down options, just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> will do (note <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> will work on current file only though). It could even accept (or require!) the parameter types, won't matter. Anything like that would be a huge thanks. Some place where I can paste a single string on (in any way that it may have to be) to open a specific method.

I've been looking for a while, could be built-in or configured shortcut, macro, plugin, et cetera, but could neither find nor wrap my head around doing something (not expert on eclipsetalities)... I tried searching for a lot different stuff, but as you can see my problem can be solved with a vast pletora of things (none of which I can find anywhere though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse jdt doesn't have it yet, but I believe an open method dialog similar to the open type dialog is in the works.. Please create a bug at bugs.eclipse.org if one doesn't exist describing what you would want in such a dialog.